# Display TMENU.2 even if it has no submenu points (but content)

Tags: typo3, typoscript

This may sound strange, but I have a menu where the first page has no real subpages. However, it has an appended COA with 2 custom TMENU's and a plugin insertion.

But: The subnavigation for this page is only generated when I add a visible subpage to this page (which would be a workaroud). Is there a better solution to get this menu visible?

Here's the typoscript:

```
field_main_navigation = HMENU
field_main_navigation {

    1 = TMENU
    1 {
        expAll = 1

        NO. wrapItemAndSub = <div class="wrap-itemAndSub">|</div>

        ACT < .NO
        ACT = 1
        ACT.ATagParams = class="active"
    }

    2 = TMENU
    2 {
        wrap = <div class="sub clearfix" style="display: none;">|</div>

        # Custom build for page 2
        stdWrap.wrap.append = COA
        stdWrap.wrap.append {
            if.value.field = pid
            if.equals = 2

            # a lot of typoscript, basically:
            # two COA's, one with two HMENU, the 
            # other one with plugin content
            10 = COA
            # ...

            20 = COA
            # ...
        }


        NO = 1
        NO {
            allWrap = <li>|</li>
        }
    }
}
```

**To explain what I want to achieve**
Basically it is a simple "show submenu on hover". Just the first item
has special content in its hover submenu. Because there are no actual
subpages that [ nav 1 ] contains, no submenu is rendered.

```
[ nav 1 ] [ nav 2 ] [ nav 3 ]
|------div.sub style="display: none;" *-------|
|  ( Custom TMENU )  |    (Plugin Content)    |
|                    |                        |
|--------------------|------------------------|
|  ( Custom TMENU )  |    ( Usual submenu ** )|
|                    |                        |
|---------------------------------------------|

* Pops out when hovering over [ nav 1 ]

** this _may_ be the case in the future, but 
   currently not. here's the problem
```

That lead me to another question (just now): Should I do all this in my usual HMENU/TMENU or should I render a normal HMENU/TMENU and prepend nav-1 as a typoscript-generated custom navigation point with custom subnavigation layer?

Comment: As your custom content should be placed after the submenu, that is equivalent to placing where I put **XXX** in this, right?  `NO.wrapItemAndSub = <div class="wrap-itemAndSub">|XXX</div>`

Comment: updated question (with another question at the bottom..)

Comment: If the items in the first level don't change (that is page with UID 2 is always there), then you can simply place that together with your custom TypoScript before the menu and exclude that page in the `HMENU`. My answer takes into account that that page might not be there. Does it work for you?

Comment: works more or less, the problem is within the submenu. but I accept it because it is a solid solution. thank you!

Comment: What's the problem in the submenu?

Comment: that, when the customer wants to add custom pages to it, it will generate two submenus. easy thing, he's just not allowed to add something ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place your custom content on the first level menu setup. Try this:

```
field_main_navigation = HMENU
field_main_navigation {
  1 = TMENU
  1 {
    expAll = 1

    NO.wrapItemAndSub {
      append = COA
      append {
        if {
          value.field = uid
          equals = 2
        }

        # a lot of typoscript, basically:
        # two COA's, one with two HMENU, the 
        # other one with plugin content
        10 = COA
        # ...

        20 = COA
        # ...
      }

      wrap3 = <div class="wrap-itemAndSub">|</div>
    }

    ACT < .NO
    ACT = 1
    ACT.ATagParams = class="active"
  }

  2 = TMENU
  2 {
    wrap = <div class="sub clearfix" style="display: none;">|</div>

    NO = 1
    NO {
      allWrap = <li>|</li>
    }
  }
}
```

**NOTE**: I'm a bit confused by the wrap on the second TMENU. Do any of the 1st level items have any real subpages?

Comment: to your note: yes, they will, in the future. so the secondlevel-menu that should pop up when hovering over the firstlevel-item is always the same. just the very first entry (uid 2) has some additional content in it.

Comment: changed it a bit to keep a valid order for html/css. instead of `wrapItemAndSub { append ` I did `after.cObject { ` so i could keep the usual `wrapItemAndSub = <...`